# Does a 24bit wav file's data chunk have signed or unsigned bytes?

Tags: java, byte, wav, signed, 24-bit

I am trying to write a program that will create 24 bit wav files using java.  The java sound api does not support 24 bit audio so I am trying to write the file from scratch.  This started out as a casual interest but it has become an epic quest of bits, bytes, signs and chunks.

Does a 24bit wav file's data chunk have signed or unsigned bytes?

Java's lack of unsigned bytes is frustrating.  I have read that bit masked integers can be used to represent unsigned bytes but I wonder how that will be represented in the final output to file.

Sorry to diverge... my question is "Does a 24bit wav file's data chunk have signed or unsigned bytes?"

Either way I am going to have to figure out this signed/unsigned business but I can't find an answer regarding the data chunk in the references I have found.

Comment: A .wav file is just a container. The actual signedness of the sample data is up to whatever codec was used to store the audio.

Answer (score 2):

I can also confirm that 24 bit data in WAV files is signed (when the data is stored in the WAVE_FORMAT_PCM format).  More generally, WAVE_FORMAT_PCM data is always signed EXCEPT when it is 8-bits per sample.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I had a feeling that was the case but I couldn't find any specific confirmation.  Most of the information I found on the web was regarding 16 bit audio in waves.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/) (and my own personal experience) Microsoft WAVE files use 2's-complement signed integers to represent PCM samples larger than 8 bits. By default, the byte-order of those integers is little-endian.

You can use `soxi` from the [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) package to verify this on your own test files (you do have some, right?).

Please note that WAVE files can also hold audio formats other than plain PCM.

Comment: Thanks, that tool looks to be very useful.  I looked at that very web page yesterday a few times but I missed that link somehow.

Comment: The link is dead. Here is the link to archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20110720050155/https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/